# $\int f(x)\cos(nx) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

$\int f(x)\cos(nx) dx$

$f (x)$ is a continuous function in the interval $[0,1]$.

Show that $\int_{0} ^ {1}\left(f (x) \cos (nx)\right) dx$ converges to zero.

I want to use $f (x)$ as a continuous function, so it is a uniformly continuous function and $f (x)$ is bounded.

Who can help?

Comment: I think this is Riemann-Lebesgue lemma!

Comment: @MyGlasses Can not you use uniformly continuous functions?
I did not learn Lesbesgue's integral theory.

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Lemma whether it is yours on not!

Comment: @MyGlasses Sorry. I do not understand. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: For a basic proof consider the continuity definition of $f$.

Comment: @MyGlasses Sorry.
First, I'll try it again.
thank you for helping me

Comment: @MyGlasses I understood what you were going to say! Can you use real analtsis instead of complex theory?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Another proof uses the idea: $\int_0^1 f(x) \cos(nx) \, dx = -\int_0^1 f(x - \frac{\pi}{n}) \cos(nx) \, dx$ by translating the function and using periodicity of $\cos$.  But on the other hand, by uniform continuity of $f$, the two integrals (ignoring sign change) aren't that different from each other.  (This assumes you extend $f$ to be periodic, so the latter integral makes sense for $x < \frac{\pi}{n}$.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler I solved it! thank you

Comment: @MyGlasses I solved it! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*HINT*

> *Proposition*:
>
> Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ a Riemman integrable function.Then $\forall \epsilon>0$ exists a step function $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_a^b|f(x)-g(x)| \leq \epsilon$

*First step*

Show that the statement holds for any function $f =1_{[a,b]}$ where $[a,b]\subseteq [0,1]$

*Second step*

Then show that it holds for any step function $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $[a,b] \subseteq [0,1]$

> A step fucntion is a function $g=\sum_{i=1}^mc_i 1_{A_i}(x)$ where the $A_i$'s are intervals.

*Third step*

Finally use the proposition to derive the result for the general Riemman itegrable $f$

Comment: Thank you! I'll try.
Can not you use f (x) as a continuous function?

Comment: A continuous function is Riemman integrable..so the result of the proposition holds again.If i understand your question

Comment: I've been worried, but I do not know how to use the proposition. Do you have to divide the interval phi / 2n ~ 3phi / 2n .. like this?

Comment: @LeeHanWoong no you dont...you will use the proposition in the 3rd step...for the first    steps just do the calculations..the second step is an immidiate outcome of the first step..

Comment: I solved it! thank you